# Highstock show/hide serie

Tags: highcharts, legend

I am having a strange response when I show/hide series clicking in the legend. When I hide a serie the other is incorrectly drawn.

Here is my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/JorgeDuenasLerin/kkE8h/36/

This is the code of the initialization

```
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
            yAxis : [{
                height : 180,
                lineWidth : 2
            }, {
                top : 220,
                height : 180,
                lineWidth : 2
            }],
        rangeSelector : {
            selected : 5
        },
            tooltip: {
                shared: true
            },
            legend : {
                enabled : true
            },
        title : {
            text : 'AAPL Stock Price'
        },
        series : [
            {
                name : 'Click on Me!',
                data : data,
                yAxis: 0,
                tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 2
                }
            },
            {
                name : 'Click on Me!',
                data : data2,
                yAxis: 1,
                tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 2
                }
            }
        ]
    });
```

Someone knows something about it?

Comment: Code added. I use the jsfiddle to show this behaviour so there is no more code apart from the initialization. ¿Any reason apart of it for the down vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed it looks like a known bug reported here: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2348

Comment: Hi Sebastian, you are right. I have put a work around with no need of disable dataGrouping. Thanks